# ציורים ממתנות כהונה לא, יא Page in Midrash Rabbah

Tags: jewish-books, midrash

I found a page at the back of Midrash Rabbah with that title and rows of boxes. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Can you maybe include a picture? And what edition is this? The more info you provide the more likely you'll get a good answer

Comment: Probably referring to https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14385#p=71&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=. In which case those are floor plans of (each of the three floors of) Noach's ark according to R. Yehudah and R. Nechemiah in the Midrash there.

Comment: Meir- that’s exactly what it is! Thank you! Looks the same just horizontal and newer. Double AA- I tried to put in a picture when I posted it but the picture was too big. It’s the ArtScroll Kleinman Edition.